# How to visualize PerspectiveCamera of the three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was reading the tutorial on how to draw lines in three.js documentation and the code used looked like this:

The code is fine and have no problems.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="///C:/Users/pc/Desktop/threejs_tutorial/build_threejs.html"></script>
        <script>
        
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );
        camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );
        camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        //create a blue LineBasicMaterial
        const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );

        const points = [];
        points.push( new THREE.Vector3( - 10, 0, 0 ) );
        points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ) );
        points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 ) );

        const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );

        const line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );


        scene.add( line );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But what caught my eye is the PerspectiveCamera part of the code.

```
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );
```

The first number is the field of view, the second number is the aspect ratio, the third number is the distance from the camera to the near viewing plane and the fourth is the distance from the camera to the far viewing plane.

How do we visualize the PerspectiveCamera of the three.js? Does it look like this one I imagined?

[PerspectiveCameraVisualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE1io.jpg)

Comment: Yep, that’s exactly it! The only detail worth mentioning is that the height is determined by the field-of-view angle (degrees), not by the window height (pixels). Then the width of the frustum is based on this height multiplied by the aspect ratio. `w = h * (innerW / innerH)`

Comment: @Marquizzo Ahhh I see....the height can be determined using trigonometry if the distance from the camera to the near viewing plane and the angle of the field of view are known. I now understand....Thank you!

Comment: @Marquizzo Oooh wait. This innerW and innerH....are they the dimensions of your computer screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualizing PerspectiveCamera of three.js really does look like this:

[truePerspectiveCameraVisualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIDh7.jpg)

[image: truePerspectiveCameraVisualization2]
Height is determined using trigonometry if the distance from the camera to the near viewing plane and the angle of the field of view are known.

Width is determined by height multiplied by the aspect ratio w = h * (innerW / innerH).